# react-jsonschema-form collapses the size of my array form and cuts off buttons

Tags: css, reactjs, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

I've started building a form in react-jsonschema-form and i'm having a lot of difficulty changing it visually.
The form is an array and it has a button to add and remove a set of input boxes.
I've build it as a component in a test project which has no css applied to it so far.

The form will render as a tiny box where there is no room for the buttons (they are cut of as shown below in images).

[a single element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVr2H.png)

[a second element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep7IS.png)

[How its supposed to look on react-jsonschema-form playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjcOy.png)

A key difference between my array and the sample array is that i'm having two text input elements per array element. I dont know if this could cause it.
I do need to have two input values as its a group of data that is related, and both is required.

This is my code:

```
//json schema
const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    listOfNumbers: {
      title: "opret ledig nummerserie",
      type: "array",
      required: ["nr_fra", "nr_til"],
      items: {
        properties: {
          nr_fra: {
            type: "string",
            pattern: "^\\d*$",
            minLength: 8,
            maxLength: 8,
          },
          nr_til: {
            type: "string",
            pattern: "^\\d*$",
            minLength: 8,
            maxLength: 8,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```
//uiSchema
const uiSchema = {
  listOfNumbers: {
    "ui:options": {
      orderable: false,
    },
    items: {
      //nr_fra: { "ui:options": { label: false } },
      //nr_til: { "ui:options": { label: false } },
    },
  },
}
```

I'm applying no css to the below form.

```
// Form
<Form
  schema={schema}
  uiSchema={uiSchema}
  formData={this.state.formData}
  onSubmit={(formOutput) => this.handleSubmit(formOutput)}
  transformErrors={transformErrors}
/>
```

I've spent a day and a half on trying to strongarm this, but i could really use some help on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was css inputs that was needed to solve this.

The below will expand the elements to their proper size/form.

Posting this here for posterity, as this is not accurately documented.

```
<div className="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    <Form schema={schema} 
          uiSchema={uiSchema}>
    </Form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you figure out why the buttons were not rendered properly? I am facing the exact same issue but that div does nothing for me. Any help would be appreciated.